# Yii redirect to custom error-page URL when throw 404 error in site/error

Tags: yii, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I need to redirect to http://example.com/error-page when throw 404 or any other error instead to render content of error page on same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe Yii docs are your friend:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action

Comment: Or I do not understand something, or a method described in the documents does not redirect to the error page URL and simply gives 404 headers and renders the content of 404 page. `public function actionError() { if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) { if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) { echo $error['message']; } if (Yii::app()->errorHandler->error['code'] == 404) { $this->render('error404', $error); } else { $this->render('error', $error); } } }`

Comment: Did you set the error handler in the application configuration? : 
 `return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
    ),
);`

Comment: Yep, even try to add rule in URLManager, no effect.

Comment: Things i would try: 1. Remove if-logic from actionError. Try to get a var_dump($error). 2. See where Yii handles its error pages itself and follow the steps. 3. Last resort: replace the Yii's own error handler if all else fails

Comment: Did you try this? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510026/yii-custom-error-pages-like-404-403-500>

Comment: Yes, problem solved, there was confusion in the formulation of the problem, in the end it was not necessary to change anything.